# Validating multiple EditTexts

Tags: android

Been stuck on this all night and there just doesn't seem to be an easy solution to it. I'm trying to validate all 4 of my fields to ensure that there is a value in each one of them, if there's a value in each one of them after I click the Calculate button a total will be calculated. If any of them don't have a value in them it'll return an error at every EditText which doesn't have a value and a total will not be calculated.

```
cal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                if( eLoan.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
                {
                    eLoan.setError( "A value is required" );
                }
                else if( eWage.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
                {
                    eWage.setError( "A value is required" );
                }
                else if( eGrant.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
                {
                    eGrant.setError( "A value is required" );
                }
                else if( eOther.getText().toString().length() == 0 )
                {
                    eOther.setError( "A value is required" );
                }
                else
                convertToString();
                converToDouble();               
                inTotal = inLoan + inWage + inGrant + inOther;
                DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat(".00");
                TotalInNum.setText("£" + currency.format(inTotal));
            }

        });
```

I can't get my head around it, I've tried to incorporate a boolean statement to check each EditText but it didn't work either. I'm convinced there's an easier method to do this.

I'm quite new to android, self teaching myself it so I would appreciate it if people could advise me on what I'm doing wrong and maybe give me an example of what I should do.

Thanks to all who respond.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is you're missing curlies at the last `else`, where the logic sits. As it is right now, only `convertToString();` is part of that last `else` and the last four statements will execute no matter what error you're setting.

Try this:

```
cal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        boolean failFlag = false;
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        if( eLoan.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 )
        {
            failFlag = true;
            eLoan.setError( "A value is required" );
        }
        if( eWage.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 )
        {
            failFlag = true;
            eWage.setError( "A value is required" );
        }
        if( eGrant.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 )
        {
            failFlag = true;
            eGrant.setError( "A value is required" );
        }
        if( eOther.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0 )
        {
            failFlag = true;                
            eOther.setError( "A value is required" );
        }
        // if all are fine
        if (failFlag == false) {
            convertToString();
            converToDouble();               
            inTotal = inLoan + inWage + inGrant + inOther;
            DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat(".00");
            TotalInNum.setText("£" + currency.format(inTotal));
        }
    }

});
```

This code will set more than one error, if more exist. Yours will signal only the first found error.

Comment: This works perfectly. I had problems getting more than 1 error, however when I put all the if statements in the first if statement I could get them in order but never the 2nd/ 3rd/ 4th EditText on it's own. Thanks a million! Was so frustrating no knowing what to do.

Comment: I have a extra doubt, I have Four Edit Text, When any one have value, it going forward. if four have null error occurred How it is check

Answer (score 6):

Just to build on what others have said. You can do something like this...

Make a validation method that loops through your EditTexts, checks if they're empty, if true set error and then returns true or false...

```
public boolean validateEditText(int[] ids)
{
    boolean isEmpty = false;

    for(int id: ids)
    {
        EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(id);

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(et.getText().toString()))
        {
            et.setError("Must enter Value");
            isEmpty = true;
        }
    }

    return isEmpty;
}
```

Make a list of you EditText id's..

```
int[] ids = new int[]
{
    R.id.section1_item1_textfield,
    R.id.section1_item2_textfield,
    R.id.section1_item3_textfield
};
```

Now use your validation method to check if empty...

```
if(!validateEditText(ids)) 
{
    //if not empty do something
}else{
    //if empty do somethingelse
}
```

To use the method above you will need to...

```
import android.text.TextUtils;
```

The good thing about doing it this way is that you can simply chuck all of your EditTexts into the list and it does the rest for you. Maintaining a huge chunk of if statements can be annoying and time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve this problem is the example below:

```
private boolean verifyIfEditTextIsFilled(EditText... editText) {

    boolean result = true;

    for (EditText text : editText) {

        if (text.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

            final View focusView = text;
            text.setError(getString(R.string.error_required));
            focusView.requestFocus();
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

late answer But may Help someone in need.

Simplest way -->

Create method as below

```
public Boolean validateUserInput()
    {
        Boolean isAnyFieldsEmpty=false;

        if (position.getText().toString()==null || position.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            position.setError("Empty postion");
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=true;
        }
        else{
            position.setError(null);
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=false;
        }

        if (eligiblity.getText().toString()==null || eligiblity.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            eligiblity.setError("Empty postion");
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=true;
        }
        else{
            eligiblity.setError(null);
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=false;
        }

        if (skillsRequired.getText().toString()==null || skillsRequired.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            skillsRequired.setError("Empty postion");
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=true;
        }
        else{
            skillsRequired.setError(null);
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=false;
        }

        if (desc.getText().toString()==null || desc.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            desc.setError("Empty postion");
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=true;
        }
        else{
            desc.setError(null);
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=false;
        }

        if (interviewFrmDate.getText().toString()==null || interviewFrmDate.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            interviewFrmDate.setError("choose date");
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=true;
        }else{
            interviewFrmDate.setError(null);
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=false;
        }

        if (interviewToDate.getText().toString()==null || interviewToDate.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            interviewToDate.setError("choose date");
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=true;
        }else{
            interviewToDate.setError(null);
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=false;
        }

        if (interviewToTime.getText().toString()==null || interviewToTime.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            interviewToTime.setError("choose date");
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=true;
        }else{
            interviewToTime.setError(null);
            isAnyFieldsEmpty=false;
        }

        return isAnyFieldsEmpty;
    }
```

Now on your Button click 
call that method as below and validate

```
@overide
public void onclick
{
Boolean isinputEmpty=validateUserInput()
if(isinputEmpty==false)
{

///process your save or whatever processing it is
}

}
```